# Combinatorics and Permutations

Tags: combinatorics

Prove that the number of permutations of at most *m* A's and at most *n* B's equals

(m + n + 2 choose m + 1) -1

Comment: How many C's are you allowed to use? Or are you only allowed to use A's and B's?

Comment: Just A's and B's

Answer (score 4):

I'm assuming you are only allowed to use A's and B's.

Consider a string of $m+n+2$ A's and B's, with $m+1$ A's (and $n+1$ B's). We now pick the string that is between the first $A$ and the last $B$. This will lead to a string of at most $m$ A's and at most $n$ B's. However, since we require the first $A$ to occur before the last $B$, we have to rule out the sequence of $BB\ldots BBBAA\ldots AA$.

It is clear that for all the other sequences, we get a bijection. (How would you define the inverse function?)

Hence, the number of ways is ${m+n+2 \choose m+1} - 1$.

Answer (score 1):

Calvin Lin has given a nice combinatorial solution. If you know the binomial identity

$$\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{m+k}m=\binom{m+n+1}{m+1}\;,$$

you can give a purely algebraic calculation:

$$\begin{align*}
\sum_{k=0}^n\sum_{j=0}^m\binom{k+j}j&=\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{k+m+1}{k+1}\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{m+k+1}m\\
&=\sum_{k=1}^{n+1}\binom{m+k}m\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^{n+1}\binom{m+k}m-\binom{m}m\\
&=\binom{m+n+1}{m+1}-1\;.
\end{align*}$$